# css change hover size depending on header length

Tags: css, hover

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEzSJ.jpg)

Hello im very new to this. I have created a webpage with links running horizontally across the page. When i hover over each title it has a background  colour. However the hover size is a fixed size. I want to know how i can get the hover to automatically adjust depending on link length. 
    /* change the link color to #272727 on hover */

```
li a:hover
    {
        background-color:#272727;
        max-width:200px;
    }
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Please provide fiddle with html too. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the "max-width: 200px;" CSS property isn't required. So try:

```
li a:hover
{
    background-color:#272727;
}
```

Without specifying an explicit max width, your link elements will size to the width of their parent li. So when you set the background colour on hover, the entire word will be highlighted, without any overflow.

But if you could provide a fiddle to confirm, that'd be really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If m not wrong then i think i got your solution. You are asking that how can you give background color on hover without changing the size or might be you are facing issue with size of li while hovering so please see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/wLn1dwhp/)

I have used padding for normal `a tag`  and remove fix width from  hover. So now m just changing the background color and it will applied automatically on text/link. Please let me know if you are facing any issue. Thank you

**HTML**

```
<div>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">RESCUES</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">VEHICLES</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">VOLUNTEERS</a></li>
     <div style="clear:both;"></div>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{background-color:teal;width:100%;}
li a:hover{background-color:#272727; color:#fff;}
li a{ padding:6px;}
ul li{list-style-type:none;float:left;padding:6px;}
li a {text-decoration:none;}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, i have spent hours trying to figure that out!! It works perfectly

Comment: My pleasure..and if it helps you then please accept as answer. :)